# How to access message from ActiveMQ Queue using MessageID? (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, activemq-classic, message-queue

I am currently subscribing to Destination Queue via the STOMP package in Python, and need to retrieve a message from the response queue based on the input message-ID. I tried using this syntax but it failed. Is there any other alternative? Any insight is appreciated!

```
Connection.subscribe(destination = Qname, id = ‘1’,ack=‘client’,conf={‘message-id :MsgID})
```

Comment: How is the message being sent? Does the message contain a property named `message-id`?

Answer (score 0):

For a message which has a property named `message-id` whose value is, for example, `123` you would use the `selector` header when subscribing, e.g.:

```py
Connection.subscribe(destination = Qname, id = '1', ack = 'client', conf = {'selector': 'message-id = 123'})
```

See the [ActiveMQ STOMP documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html) for more details.